# gevent TCP server on Windows

Tags: python, windows, tcp, nonblocking, gevent

I've been trying to create a TCP server with gevent without (any major) success so far. I think that the problem lies within Windows ( I've had some issues with sockets under Windows before ). I'm using Python2.7, gevent0.13 under Windows7. Here's my code:

```
from gevent import socket
from gevent.server import StreamServer

def handle_echo(sock, address):
    try:
        fp = sock.makefile()
        while True:
            # Just echos whatever it receives
            try:
                line = fp.readline()
            except Exception:
                break
            if line:
                try:
                    fp.write(line)
                    fp.flush()
                except Exception:
                    break
            else:
                break
    finally:
        sock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
        sock.close()

server = StreamServer(("", 2345), handle_echo)
server.server_forever()
```

This implementation is similar to the one you can find here:

http://blog.pythonisito.com/2012/08/building-tcp-servers-with-gevent.html

Now there are no errors and the server seems to work correctly, however it is not reading ( and thus sending ) anything. Is it possible that `sock.makefile()` does not work correctly under Windows7? Or maybe the problem lies somewhere else?

I've tried to replace `sock.makefile()` with simple

```
while True:
    line = sock.recv(2048)
```

but this operation obviously blocks.

I've also tried to mix gevent's `spawn` with `sock.setblocking(0)`. Now this was better and it worked, however it would not handle more then ~300 connections at a time.

I'm going to do some tests on Linux and see if it makes difference. In the meantime if you have any ideas, then feel free to share them with me. Cheers!

**UPDATE** Original code does the same thing under Ubuntu 12.04. So how should I implement gevent TCP server??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you send to the server? Make sure it's terminated by newline.. otherwise readline() won't work.

You could also use tcpdump or wireshark to see what's happening at TCP layer if you think you're doing correct things in your code.

Comment: Unbelievable. I've been so focused on complex things that I've missed the obvious one. :) Yes, I've been sending `"ping"` all the time. I've changed it to `"ping\n"` and now it works as it should! Thank you very much! By the way: I've compared its performance to the performance of its threaded version and it actually seems that threaded version is more efficient! I might still be doing something wrong but I guess it's not related to the question now. :)